# How to calculate volatility and trends in a time series analysis?

Tags: distributions, volatility-forecasting, pandas

I have a table with data for different groups by months and totals, each groups are of different scales where the `max` and `min` values great varies. I am not sure where to start, but is there a statistical aggregation or model that I can apply to assess the volatility of the groups by its values?

Once plotted, I expect `high volatility` as a chart which have lots of spikes and irregular distribution over the months and `low volatility` as having a a rather flat trend over the months.

After which I am curious, to see whether certain groups have similar distributions over the months. I have always been visualizing the work I have done but in my current case, there are hundreds of groups and I do not think it will be feasible.

Thanks in advance and I hope somebody here will be able to point me the right way.